# Information needed on PHP upgradation

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2

i need to upgrade the PH version on Windows 2008R2 Server-

Current version - PHP Version 5.2.13
Upgraded version needed - PHP Version 5.3.27

is this up-gradation affect on previous version scripting and functions ?

Comment: See the [PHP Migration guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php) for details on the changes.

Comment: as far as i know between 5.2.13 and 5.3.27 there was no major changes

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you're looking for is simply 'upgrade' not 'up-gradation'. The answer is that it is perfectly OK to run two versions of PHP side-by-side.

One way to do this is to have your main version of php set up with mod_php and run all of the others through fast cgi on different ports (i.e. 81, 82, 83 etc).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the particular problems happen

But you can find all of your question in this link

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration52.php